# How do I make it so that numbers are being read so I can calculate the average

Tags: c++

```
    cout << "\nName of File name: ";
    cin >> (fileName);
    readFile.open(fileName);    //opens the file

    if (!readFile.is_open()) //if file is open/exists
    {
        cout << "! ! File does not exist ! !" << endl;
        goto Start;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    if (readFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(readFile, line)) //read line by line
        {
            cout << line << "\n";
        }
    }
    readFile.close();
    goto Start;
```

I only have these set of codes to read the text files line by line, and I have a text file that looks like this.

```
Students    Math    Science    English
Student1    78      87         23
Student2    77      82         95
Student3    86      56         46
```

How can I see and use the grades so it comes out as integers because I need to use them for calculations?

Comment: You know how to read the file line-by-line. Now you just need to read values from each line. Inside your loop, you can use `std::istringstream` and `operator>>` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Define a structure for students:

```
struct Student {
    std::string name;
    int math;
    int science;
    int english;
};
```

Provide a input operator:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Student& st) {
    in >> st.name >> st.math >> st.science >> st.english;
    return in;
}
```

And use it to store students data in a vector:

```
std::vector<Student> students;
// ... open file etc. ...
Student st;
while(readFile >> st) students.push_back(st);
```

Note that I assumed that the names do not contain whitespace characters.